# How to concatenate lists that are values of map?

Tags: scala, collections, containers, scala-collections, scala-java-interop

Given:

```
scala> var a = Map.empty[String, List[Int]]
a: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = Map()

scala> a += ("AAA" -> List[Int](1,3,4))

scala> a += ("BBB" -> List[Int](4,1,4))

scala> a
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(AAA -> List(1, 3, 4), BBB -> List(4, 1, 4))
```

How to concatenate the values to a single iterable collection (to be sorted)?

```
List(1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4)
```

How should I end this code?

```
a.values.[???].sorted
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider

```
a.flatMap(_._2)
```

which flattens up the second element of each tuple (each value in the map).

Equivalent in this case is also

```
a.values.flatMap(identity)
```

Answer (score 8):

You should end it with:

```
a.values.flatten
```

Result:

```
scala> Map("AAA" -> List(1, 3, 4), "BBB" -> List(4, 1, 4))
res50: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(AAA -> List(1, 3, 4), BBB -> List(4, 1, 4))

scala> res50.values.flatten
res51: Iterable[Int] = List(1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4)
```

Updated:

For your specific case it's:

```
(for(vs <- a.asScala.values; v <- vs.asScala) yield v.asInstanceOf[TargetType]).sorted
```

Answer (score 7):

This will work

```
 a.values.flatten                              
//> res0: Iterable[Int] = List(1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

My appreciation of all answers I have received. Finally good points led to really working code. Below is real code fragment and `x` here is `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put` which makes all the 'devil in the details'. I needed HBase `Put` to be converted into list of appropriate data cells (accessible from puts through `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.Cell` interface) but yet I need disclosure of the fact they are indeed implemented as `KeyValue` (`org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue`).

```
val a : Put ...

a.getFamilyCellMap.asScala
    .flatMap(
        _._2.asScala.flatMap(
            x => List[KeyValue](x.asInstanceOf[KeyValue]) )
    ).toList.sorted
```

Why so complex?

- Put is Java type to represent 'write' operation content and we can get its cells only through map of cells families elements of which are lists. Of course they all are Java.
- I have only access to interface (`Cell`) but I need implementation (`KeyValue`) so downcast is required. I have guarantee nothing else is present.

The most funny thing after all of this I decided to drop standard `Put` and encapsulate data into different container (which is my custom class) on earlier stage and this made things much more simple.

So more generic answer for this case where a is `java.util.Map[?]` with values of `java.util.List[?]` and elements of list are of `BaseType` but you need `TargetType is probably:

```
a.asScala.flatMap(
    _._2.asScala.flatMap(
        x => List[TargetType](x.asInstanceOf[TargetType]) )
).toList.sorted
```

Comment: why you can't just `a.asScala.values.flatMap(_.asScala).map(_.asInstanceOf[TargetType]).sorted`?